# useState Typescript Error: Argument of type 'prev' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When implementing that code

```
export const resetErrors = (setErrors: (errors: Array<ErrorInterface>) => void, field: string): void => setErrors((prev: Array<ErrorInterface>): void => prev.filter((el: ErrorInterface) => el.field !== field));
```

the following error occurs:
**Argument of type '(prev: Array) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ErrorInterface[]'.ts(2345)**
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Let's rewrite the single-line code to something like below:

```js
function resetErrors(setErrors: (errors: Array<ErrorInterface>) => void, field: string): void {

  function filterByField(prev: Array<ErrorInterface>): void {
    function removeFieldFilter(el: ErrorInterface) {
      return el.field !== field;
    }
    return prev.filter(removeFieldFilter); // <- Error: Type 'ErrorInterface[]' is not assignable to type 'void'.ts(2322)
  }

  return setErrors(filterByField); // <- Error: Argument of type '(prev: ErrorInterface[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ErrorInterface[]'.ts(2345)
}

export {
  resetErrors,
}
```

This way it's easier to spot some errors in the code.

1. `filterByField` is declared to return `void` but it's returning the `prev.filter(sameFieldFilter)`, an array of `ErrorInterface`;
2. `setErrors` is declared as a function with one parameter, an array of `ErrorInterface`, but it's being called with a function instead;

To fix those:

1. The `void` should be removed so the compiler implicitly deduces it;
2. `resetErrors` is missing the `prev` parameter;

It's going to be the following:

```js
function resetErrors(prev: Array<ErrorInterface>, setErrors: (errors: Array<ErrorInterface>) => void, field: string): void {

  function filterByField(prev: Array<ErrorInterface>) {
    function removeFieldFilter(el: ErrorInterface) {
      return el.field !== field;
    }
    return prev.filter(removeFieldFilter);
  }

  return setErrors(filterByField(prev));
}

export {
  resetErrors,
}
```

the one line fixed version:

```js
export const resetErrors = (prev: Array<ErrorInterface>, setErrors: (errors: Array<ErrorInterface>) => void, field: string): void => setErrors(prev.filter((el: ErrorInterface) => el.field !== field));
```